# Need to find element in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I want to find the element of these inputs:"Email" and "Mot de passe" to fill it by the next.
Any help will be highly appreciated
Here is the url: https://www.geev.com/fr/login/local

I tried these but don't work with me:

```
List<WebElement> someElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'view-login-form-password-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid')]"));

List<WebElement> someElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".view-login-form-password-input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid")); 

List<WebElement> someElements = driver.findElements(By.className("input.view-login-form-password-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"));

    for (WebElement anElement : someElements) {
        if (anElement.getAttribute("type").equals("email")) {
            // Do something
            anElement.sendKeys("");         }
    }
```

**Edit 1:**

Thanks @wp78de for your suggestions only this one works but unfortunately, it's referring to search input and not to "Email" and "Mot de passe" inputs

```
WebElement anElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*/form[1]/input[1]"));
```

And later I tried this for my second form but doesn't work :(

```
WebElement anElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*/form[2]/input[1]"));
```

Comment: How about `//*/form[1]/input[1]`, `//*/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]`, and the button `//body/div[2]/iframe[1]`.

Comment: @wp78de thanks for your help, I have tried your suggestions only  //*/form[1]/input[1], works but unfortunately it's referring to search input and not to "Email" and "Mot de passe" inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send to email and pass use the following.

```
WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='email']"));
userName.sendKeys("Username");
WebElement passWord = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='password']"));
passWord.sendKeys("Pass");
```

I used it after this.

```
driver.get("https://www.geev.com/fr/login/local");
driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I used this before but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Worked on mine did you wait before looking for the elements.

Comment: It's amazing it's working with me too after let my drive waiting for 10 seconds